# Copy&Paste Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I want to be able to copy and paste text into my ubuntu server which is just a terminal. I installed the virtualbox guest additions but it doesn't help.

Everythign is instaleld successfully althought i get the Message: "The headers for the current running kernel were not found. If the following compilation fails then this could be the reason" I don't know, why it is saying, the headers were not found. Also, it doesnt seem to matter since there was not error following this warning.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following command:

```
apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Comment: Already tried this, which just gives me: "linux-header-3.5.0.17-generic is already the newest version. But thanks

Comment: What `uname -a` prints? Did you try `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` ?